# Read contents from what io.Writer writes

Tags: go, io

There's a library that exports a file but I'd like to capture the contents of the file. I'd like to pass a writer to the library and be able to read what the writer wrote to the file. Eventually i want to augment the library to skip writing this file. 
Is this possible with io.Copy or io.Pipe?

The library code creates a *File and uses this handle as an io.Writer.
I tried using io.Copy but only 0 bytes were read.

```
func TestFileCopy(t *testing.T) {

codeFile, err := os.Create("test.txt")
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
defer codeFile.Close()
codeFile.WriteString("Hello World")
n, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, codeFile)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
log.Println(n, "bytes")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to capture the bytes as they are written, use an [`io.MultiWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter) with a `bytes.Buffer` as the second writer.

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
w := io.MultiWriter(codeFile, &buf)
```

or to see the file on stdout as it's written:

```
w := io.MultiWriter(codeFile, os.Stdout)
```

Otherwise, if you want to re-read the same file, you need to seek back to the start after writing:

```
codeFile.Seek(0, 0)
```

Comment: Or since in the example he wants the output on the console, he can pass `os.Stdout` as the 2nd writer: `w := io.MultiWriter(codeFile, os.Stdout)`.

Comment: The `io.Multiwriter` documentation example provides clarity on the usage. First setup all the writers using `io.MultiWriter`, and then call `io.Copy`. So one can go `io.MultiWriter(codeFile, &buf, os.Stdout)`